# Как получить данные через GET запрос Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть простая модель /model.py, в бд уже хранится два объекта с именем и номером тлф. Дело собственно в том, что в object_list получаю `<QuerySet [<Customer: Dima>, <Customer: Andrey>]>`, при попытке получить номер методом `object_list.number` вылетает ошибка мол `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'number'`.

Вопрос 1 - Как вытащить номер из модели? (при итерации выдает только первый встречающийся объект)

Вопрос 2 - Есть ли другие способы организовать эту процедуру?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Есть /views.py

```
class Search(ListView):
    model = Customer()
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Customer.objects.filter(number__icontains=query)

        return object_list
```

Есть /serach.html и /urls.py

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
    <label>
        <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </label>
</form>

<ul>
    {{ object_list }}
</ul>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Search


urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', Search.as_view(), name='search')
]
```

Answer (score 2):

у тебя     {{ object_list }} это список, если хочешь вывести какое-то поле, то пробегись по списку в шаблоне

```
{% for my_object in object_list %}
  {{ my_object.number }} - {{ my_object.name }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: О, недодумался сам, интересно то, что, когда пробегаюсь во вьюхе, выдает только первый попавшийся объект, дальше будто нету, а в шаблоне все норм, спасибо!